# multiple text like search in same column in sql

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search

Better way to perform multiple text like search in same column in tsql

| EmpNo | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Security Part Time |
| 2 | Security Full-Time |
| 3 | Security Casual |
| 4 | Security FT |
| 5 | Security PT |
| 6. | Security Trainee |
| 7. | Admin Trainee |
| 8. | Admin FT |
| 9 | Security Full |

```
select *
from jobs
where type = 'Security'
  and (type like '%Full-Time%'
   or  type like '%FT%'
   or  type like  '%FullTime%')
```

Is there any better way to perform the search?

Comment: That query *isn't* using a fulltext index; does the column have one? If so, you should be using `CONTAINS`. Though the real solution would be to fix the design; if they are full/part time should be in a different column and the value should be **consistent**.

Comment: If you store the patterns in a table you can use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to check for matches. Aside: By not using delimiters between "words" you allow `'%FT%'` to match `'Kraftwerk Percussionist'`.

Comment: I'm guessing the first condition isn't `type = 'Security'` but `type like 'Security%'`, otherwise, this query will never return any records.

Comment: select *
from jobs
where type like 'Security'
  and (type like '%Full-Time%'
   or  type like '%FT%'
   or  type like  '%FullTime%')

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

1. Union All instead of or statement may be much faster if your result set for each condition is small compared to size of table, and solve your performance issue.

ie:

```
select *
from jobs
where type = 'Security'
and type like '%Full-Time%'

union all

select *
from jobs
where type = 'Security'
and type like '%FullTime%'

union all

select *
from jobs
where type = 'Security'
and type like '%FT%'
```

2. Like statement is not a full text search, but can use index if '%' is not at the beginning: ie type like 'Security%' can use an index, but like '%Full-Time%' cannot. You can index a forward and reversed column in your case.